# Exploding column by delimiter and using prefix of split column name as value

Tags: sql, presto, unpivot

I have a table with the following aggregation

| pageurl | hour01_visits | hour02_visits |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `abc.com` | 9000 | 9500 |
| `def.com` | 3000 | 2300 |

And would like to explode it like so

| pageurl | hour | visits |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `abc.com` | 01 | 9000 |
| `abc.com` | 02 | 9500 |
| `def.com` | 01 | 3000 |
| `def.com` | 02 | 2300 |

I know how to explode arrays with Presto cross join unnest but here I am exploding the columns by their name themselves. Not sure if this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use a classical approach, where you reverse the pivot operation using the `UNION ALL` operators for all of your columns

```
SELECT pageurl, 
       1             AS hour,
       hour01_visits AS visits
FROM tab
UNION ALL 
SELECT pageurl, 
       2             AS hour,
       hour02_visits AS visits
FROM tab
ORDER BY pageurl, hour
```

Yet a smarter option could be to convert your columns into a single array, and apply the `UNNEST` operation onto it, using the `WITH ORDINALITY` clause to gather the ordered ids.

```
SELECT tab.pageurl, hour, visits
FROM tab,
     UNNEST(ARRAY[hour01_visits, hour02_visits]) WITH ORDINALITY cte(visits, hour);
```

"**Output**":

| pageurl | hour | visits |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc.com | 1 | 9000 |
| abc.com | 2 | 9500 |
| def.com | 1 | 3000 |
| def.com | 2 | 2300 |

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/e6w2WWcpiaua8f2YeB6cwC/1).

Comment: Thanks for the response! Is there an alternative to the 'Ordinality' if 'hour' was not an increasing int but instead a decimal? Like 0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2,...

Comment: You can apply a division over the row number (like rownum*0.05).